# Irreversible functions to distort sound that still retain discriminatory features

Tags: distortion

Is there a way to distort a sound so that can't be restored to its original form (i.e. the function moves one way), but it doesn't add noise to the sound (you can still decipher certain features of the sound based on listening to it; no randomness is added).

Comment: Are you talking about doing it for disguising a voice like witness protection?

Comment: For the purpose of witness protection, I highly recommend just re-recording what was said and using a voice actor or a Text-to-Speech system like Google's Cloud API system. https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate a linear predictive coding mechanism like Silk or Speex. Encode the speech with said codec then decimate the bitrate down to the minimum possible intelligible level. I defy anyone to reverse the processing.

Comment: Decimating the bitrate is a great idea!!!!!! I'll look into the other ones.

Comment: using specific Speech codec is the key - the way it works is that it detects vocal inflections, tonal and noise components and then recreates the voice using parametric synthesis. The voice you hear through these codecs isn't actually real it's synthesised on a block-by-block basis.